# How to restart salt-minon daemon automatically after machine restart?

Tags: salt-stack

I've installed salt-minion on CentOS-7. Started minion using it's own user `salt` and command `salt-minion -d`.
Once the machine was restarted, `salt-minion` was not started automatically.
Suggest a clean solution.

Comment: Did you install salt-minon using the step stated here http://repo.saltstack.com/#rhel ? The latest saltstack installer should handle CentOS7 systemd for you

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 7 run the following command to ensure the salt-minion starts on boot:

```
systemctl enable salt-minion.service
```